# Location and filenames of wireless drivers on Android 5.02, Kernel 3.10.49?

Tags: applications, wi-fi, 5.0-lollipop, security, kernel

I am looking to fuzz the wireless drivers and linked / associated files on Android 5.02, kernel version 3.10.49.
I am looking for vulnerabilities in those files.

I believe I need to know what the files are called, and where they are located - this is what I'm requesting.

I have searched via google, and believe they may be part of specific builds of Linux kernel.

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! This site is for *users* of Android, which means that questions about development/programming are off-topic here (see the [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic)). Development questions are on-topic on our sister site [Stack Overflow](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android). You might also wish to consult [Where can I ask questions that aren't Android Enthusiast questions?](//meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575) for a fitting place to your question.

Comment: @izzy Hi. This is not development nor programming related in my opinion, rather is is security related. Hence to me the vote to close should be reconsidered please, and a suggestion to a better SE site for this question?

Comment: I'll reopen it as fast as I've put it on hold – but you'd need to [edit] it and make clear what it's about: What are you trying to achieve? What's the background of your question? What problem to solve? Ping me again once you've updated your post accordingly, and I'll see if I can reopen it then (expect so ;)

Comment: @izzy ok, I need to know what further details I need to specify please? - I have added what I am looking to do a moment ago & to me your other points were already covered in my question. If you don't see this please expand with specific examples

Comment: As it's not my specific area of expertise, I cannot provide all details necessary. Afraid that goes beyond the scope of this site (which is targeted at and-users of Android); while that includes "power users", looking for vulnerabilities in drivers is a bit far-fetched I'm afraid. Unfortunately you lack the rep to bring that up in Meta or discuss it on chat yourself, so I'll reopen it for now and leave it to the community to decide (5 votes from community members with sufficient rep can close this again if the community decides it doesn't fit).

Comment: @izzy can you or another move it to a better area?

Comment: If I new some "better area", I had suggested it already – so sorry, I don't know where that better place would be. As I wrote, I'm not active in that field. Checking with my co-mods on other sites, it seems Android.SE is already as close as you can get...

Comment: @izzy. I have found via search a SE site that could suit this question better. Can this question be moved to Information Security SE?

Comment: When I asked yesterday, the answer was "No": while your *goal* is security, your question is not. You're just asking for file locations.

Comment: Ok I understand. I will wait.

Comment: While waiting, you might consult [alternative sources](https://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/371/16575), as I initially pointed out. If you find a solution there, be welcome to [answer your own question](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) (and afterwards "accept" the answer to show your issue was solved).